# how to write test for json response?

Tags: php, json, unit-testing, laravel-5, laravel-5.1

I have function return JSON

```
return response()->json([
            'status' => 'OK',
            'data' => [
                'id' => $routeForecast->id,
            ],
        ])
```

how can I make test for this .. my laravel version is 5.1 and i used assertJson([ ]) it give me this error

```
***** PHPUnit_Framework_Exception: Argument #1 (No Value) of PHPUnit_Framework_Assert::assertJson() must be a string
```

and try seeJson it give me this error

```
***** Invalid JSON was returned from the route. Perhaps an exception was thrown?
```

how can i solve it ??

Answer (score 0):

Try something like this.

```
    // When
    $response = $this->getJson( 'v1/helloWorld' );

    //dd( $response ); // perhaps die and dump here to check response?

    // Then
    $response
        ->assertStatus( 200 )
        ->assertJson( [
            'status' => 'OK',
        ] );
```

Comment: i think assertJson is not use with laravel 5.1

Comment: this what i did for response
$response = $this->json('POST', '/path/en');

Comment: ahh sorry, its `seeJson` in 5.1

Comment: is this right?  $response = $this->json('POST', '/path/en');

Comment: No, looks like you should be doing `$this->post('/path/en')` or `$this->call('POST', '/path/en');`  - https://laravel.com/docs/5.1/testing#testing-json-apis

Comment: i try this form but still get this 
BadMethodCallException: Method [seeJson] does not exist on Redirect.